# qemu-kvm showing over 100% of CPU usage in top command

Tags: centos7, openstack, qemu, openstack-nova, top-command

I am running openstack on centos 7. All openstack services run within docker containers. I keep seeing high CPU usage from qemu-kvm as I launch more instances on openstack. Below is an image showing output from my top command

[image]

for about 20 seconds it will show qemu-kvm CPU usage spike to about 80% to 200% then it will go back down to about 5% or 10% for a few minutes and then back up...It keeps jumping up and down.

Not sure what is the expected CPU usage for an openstack compute node but I am wondering if this is something to worry about and what steps I should take to investigate this and how I could improve performance?